# WAMP: How to Host and Download a file?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, wamp

I know this may be an easy question, but I can't seem to find a proper answer.

I recently setup a WAMP server (with PHP 7) and I have a file I want users who access the site to be able to download. So far I have the file in a directory and all is fine.

But every time I go to the URL of the file it says

`You don't have permission to access /file/placeholder.zip on this server.`

It also gives me a 403 Forbidden error.

I have made my website public in httpd.conf, and even when I access it from the hosting machine it doesn't work. If you need more info please ask.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the leading `/` as that says go to the root folder and look for a folder called `file`

If the file is actually in a folder called `C:\file\placeholder.zip` then Apache will not have acess to that folder **for good reasons**

Assuming you are putting your site in `\wamp\www\project` and the script is in that folder, then place the file in `\wamp\www\project\folder_name\placeholder.zip` and use `folder_name/placeholder.zip` when identifying the file to send.